# Watch a directory and insert new entries into database

Tags: python, mysql, file-system

This program's main function is to:

1. Watch a directory.
2. If there are new files, insert those as entries into the database.
3. Delete the files from the directory.

My below code runs well, but I want to optimize it and I think it needs better error handling.

```python
import os
import time
import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb
import pooop

file_path = 'C:\\path\\to\\watch\\'

#send files to database
def insert_csv(file,filename):
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user',
                                    password ='pass',host='192.168.1.1',
                                  database='test')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()                             
        thedata = open(file, 'rb').read()
        sql = "INSERT INTO testing(file_backup,file_name) VALUES (%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql,(thedata,filename))
        cnx.commit()

   except MySQLdb.OperationalError, e:
      print e
   except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError, e:
      print e
   finally:
      cursor.close()

def walk():
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(file_path):
            for i in files:
                file = dirpath+i
                try:
                    insert_csv(file,i)
                except Exception, e:
                    print e                 
                finally:
                    os.remove(file)
                print 'File successfully removed\n'+"-"*80
    except Exception, e:
         print e

#main loop that watches the directory       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Application starts running\n"+"-"*80
    while True:
        walk()
```

The application will run on Windows XP. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Please do not edit your question that way as you invalidated a whole lot of @vnp answer in doing so. See [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: I did not edit the question, i edited the code to apply what vnp suggested. If it isnt allowed to apply the suggestion on the answer i will revert it back. @mathias

Comment: I see. Okay. Thank you. Ill do that. @mathias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error handling I agree that there are improvements possible, in
particular it seems dangerous to me that if a database error occurs, the
corresponding file will be deleted regardless.  Apart from that other
exceptions should be fine, e.g. if a file couldn't be deleted it will
just be retried later.

- Take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for
  formatting.  In particular constants should be written in upper case.
- The usual advice is also to not shadow predefined names like `file`.
- The comments on `insert_csv` and the main loop should rather be a
  docstrings because that way you could look at that information
  interactively.
- The way the entries are read from the file is leaking the file
  descriptor - use `with` on `open`.
- To prevent too much escaping try the `r""` format (assuming that the
  final backslash isn't necessary).
- Catching exceptions should be done with forward compatibility to
  Python 3 in mind, i.e. `except Exception as e` instead of the comma
  syntax; same goes for `print`, which should use the function syntax.
- The connection should be closed too.
- Catching exceptions this way hides the backtrace, that is often less
  useful than just letting the exception go through.
- `insert_csv` opens and closes the database connection for every file.
  That is suboptimal and I can't see a reason why it shouldn't just stay
  open - did some of these exceptions clobber the whole connection?  I
  don't understand all of the implications yet, but I'd suggest moving
  the `connect` and possibly `cursor` calls into `main` instead of
  `insert_csv`.

Some ideas for future improvements:

- Settings and parameters like the database connection and the watched
  directory should be moved into configuration and/or command line
  arguments.
- Perhaps use sqlalchemy or something with a bit nicer interface.
- Similarly, try to find some library to watch the directory without
  polling, e.g. [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/),
  because the current busy loop is really expensive comparatively.

This is a bit cleaner I believe:

```python
import os
import time
import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb
import pooop


FILE_PATH = r'C:\path\to\watch'
DB_CONNECTION = {
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    'host': '192.168.1.1',
    'database': 'test'
}


LINE = "-" * 80


def insert_csv(file, filename):
    "Send files to database."
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            thedata = f.read()
        sql = "INSERT INTO testing(file_backup, file_name) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (thedata, filename))
        cnx.commit()
   except (MySQLdb.OperationalError, MySQLdb.ProgrammingError) as e:
       print(e)
   finally:
       cursor.close()
       cnx.close()


def walk(file_path):
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(file_path):
            for i in files:
                file = dirpath + i
                try:
                    insert_csv(file, i)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                finally:
                    os.remove(file)
                print('File successfully removed')
                print(LINE)
    except Exception as e:
         print(e)


def main():
    "Main loop that watches the directory."
    print("Application starts running")
    print(LINE)
    while True:
        walk(FILE_PATH)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

- **Naming**

  Nothing in the code suggests that `csv` files are special. Why a backup is called `backup_csv`?
- **Exception handling**

  The main code removes the file regardless of the insertion success. For example, if `connect` fails, the file is still removed. Is this an intended behaviour? I recommend to call `os.remove()` inside `backup_csv`.
- **misc**

  - What is the purpose of `time.sleep(1)`?
  - I don't see a reason for `if files` clause. The `for i in files` works as expected if `files` is empty.

Comment: I have revised the code, 
for naming, i rename the backup_csv
for exception handling : if a ``connect`` fails the behaviour i want to achieve is for the program to try again to insert the file instead of removing it. @vnp