# Watch a directory and insert new entries into database - Follow up

Tags: python, mysql, file-system

This is now  my new code implementing the recommendations from my previous [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108846/watch-a-directory-and-insert-new-entries-into-database).

```
import os
import time
import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb
import ConfigParser
import base64
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import sys
import ast
import smtplib

from sendmail import send_mail
"""
TO DO:
1. Retry failure upload when mysql disconnects
"""
currdir = os.getcwd()
curr_datetime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
"""function that reads the config file"""
def read_Config(section, option):
    conf_file = currdir + "\\Config\\config.ini"
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

    config.read(conf_file)
    sections = config.sections()

    def ConfigSectionMap(section):
        dict1 = {}
        options = config.options(section)
        for option in options:
            try:
                dict1[option] = config.get(section, option)
                if dict1[option] == -1:
                    # print("skip: %s" % option)
                    LOGGER.debug("skip: %s" % option)
            except:
                deb = "exception on %s!" % option
                LOGGER.debug(deb)
                write_log(wyko_no,'DEBUG',deb,cur_datetime)
                dict1[option] = None
        return dict1

    res = ConfigSectionMap(section)[option]
    return res

"""read configuration file"""
app_name = read_Config('application','app_name')
FILE_PATH = read_Config('application','file_path')
LOG_PATH = currdir + "\\" + read_Config('application','log_path') + "\\"
USER = read_Config('database','user')
PASSWORD = read_Config('database','password')
PASSWORD = base64.decodestring(PASSWORD) ##decode password, remove D and L from the string
HOST = read_Config('database','host')
DB = read_Config('database','db')
DB_PORT = read_Config('database','port')
RECEIVERS = ast.literal_eval(read_Config('email','receivers'))
SENDER = read_Config('email','sender')
SMTP = read_Config('email','smtp')
PORT = read_Config('email','port')
"""set up logger"""
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(app_name)
LOG_FILE = app_name + '.log'
LOG_PATH = LOG_PATH + LOG_FILE
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
hdlr = TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_PATH, when="d", interval=1, backupCount=1)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s:   %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
LOGGER.addHandler(hdlr) 
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
LOGGER.addHandler(sh)


"""insert csv to database"""
def insert_csv(file,filename):
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = USER,
                                        password = PASSWORD,host = HOST,
                                      database = DB, port = DB_PORT)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()   
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            thedata = f.read()
        curr_datetime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        sql = "INSERT INTO wyko_file(wyko_file,file_name,date_inserted) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql,(thedata,filename,curr_datetime))
        if cursor.rowcount != 0:
            LOGGER.info("Transfer to database succesful!")
            cnx.commit()    
    except (MySQLdb.OperationalError, MySQLdb.ProgrammingError), e:
        LOGGER.error(e)
        send_mail(SENDER,RECEIVERS,e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()


"""main loop that watches the directory"""  
def main():

    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(FILE_PATH):
            for i in files:
                file = dirpath+i
                try:
                    LOGGER.info("Transferring file: " +i)
                    insert_csv(file,i)
                except Exception, e:
                    LOGGER.error(e)
                    send_mail(SENDER,RECEIVERS,e)
                finally:
                    os.remove(file)
                LOGGER.info('File successfully removed from '+FILE_PATH+"\n"+"-"*80)
    except Exception, e:
        LOGGER.error(e)
        send_mail(SENDER,RECEIVERS,e)
            # break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LOGGER.info("Application starts running\n"+"-"*80)
    main()
```

But upon deploying this application on a client, I have encountered an issue that this parser is eating up the resources on the client computer and causes applications to hang/lag. I think the code needs optimizing.

The parser is currently deployed on a Windows XP OS with 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Parsing configuration file

There are a few problems with your `read_Config` function:

- `ConfigParser` objects are akin to dictionaries of dictionaries: there is no need to build dictionaries out of them, they already behave as such with a few extra functionnalities;
- `read_Config` is called (and thus the file parsed) for each parameter you want to retrieve out of the file: this is a waste of resources, read the file once and return the parser object to extract parameters out of it;
- `read` method of `ConfigParser` behave the same as `open`, it accepts relative path, no need to use `getcwd` for that;
- `read` method of `ConfigParser` actually accept a list of filepaths (a single string is turned into a list of 1 element) and silently handle missing files ([rationale in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read)); your code will fail if the file is not handled so I suggest using

  ```
  with open(<path>) as config_file:
      config.readfp(config_file)
  ```

  instead to get a more descriptive error if anything goes wrong.

## Too much “constants”

A lot of your constants are dependant of the result of your `read_Config` function.

At this point you may want to introduce a class in your design to improve readability and reusability. The various “constants” initialized out of `read_Config` will become the state (attributes) of your object.

## Exception handling

You made a good point of handling specific exceptions in the method reviewed in your previous question but forgot to apply the advice in your `read_Config` function.

Also you should prefer the new style of variable naming in `except` clause using the `as` keyword: e.g. `except Exception as e`. This is the only way to write it in Python 3 and yours is considered deprecated.

## Avoid repetitions

Almost all your `except` performs the same operation. For now it’s only two lines of code but someday you might want to improve them. Maybe that the `send_mail` function only uses `str` on your exception before sending the mail, leaving out the whole stacktrace with usefull informations and at some point you’ll want to improve that.

Use a function for that: any change will be applied anywhere for free.

## Bugs?

- What is this `write_log` function in `read_Config`? You neither define it nor import it.
- In `main` you use `finally` to remove files whether or not they got into the database. You may want to use `else` instead to remove only if the sql insert succeded.
- You removed a `while True` from your last question, is it expected?

## Misc

- Not sure which way is better but you can get your `curr_daytime`s using `datetime.now().isoformat(' ')` instead of using `time`;
- Why are you using `ast` to parse the list of `RECEIVERS`? Can't you write it as a string of recipients separated by semi-colons and split it in your code?
- Docstrings are “the string written the line right after a function declaration, if any” (not before).
- `smtplib`, `SMTP` and `PORT` are never used.

## Proposed alternative

```
import os

from datetime import datetime
from sys import stdout
import logging

import mysql.connector
import MySQLdb

import base64
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

from sendmail import send_mail


def parse_config(config_filename):
    """function that reads the config file"""
    config = ConfigParser()
    with open(config_filename) as config_file:
        config.readfp(config_file)
    return config

class FolderWatcher(object):
    def __init__(self, config_filename):
        """Read configuration file and store important data out of it"""
        config = parse_config(config_filename)

        app_name = config.get('application', 'app_name')
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(app_name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - '
            '%(levelname)s:   %(message)s')
        log_path = config.get('application', 'log_path')
        handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
            os.path.join(log_path, app_name + '.log'),
            when="d", interval=1, backupCount=1)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)

        handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)

        self.watched_folder = config.get('application','file_path')

        self.mysql_credentials = {
            'user': config.get('database','user'),
            ##decode password, remove D and L from the string
            'password': base64.decodestring(config.get('database','password')),
            'host': config.get('database','host'),
            'database': config.get('database','db'),
            'port': config.get('database','port'),
        }

        self.mail_sender = config.get('email', 'sender')
        # You’ll need to modify your config file to get this line to work
        self.mail_receivers = map(str.strip,
                                  config.get('email', 'receivers').split(';'))

        self.logger.info("Application {} starts running".format(app_name))
        self.logger.info("-"*80)

    def manage_exception(self, exception):
        self.logger.error(exception)
        send_mail(self.mail_sender, self.mail_receivers, exception)

    def insert_csv(self, file_path, filename):
        """insert csv to database"""
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**self.mysql_credentials)
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                data = f.read()
            curr_datetime = datetime.now().isoformat(' ')
            sql = ("INSERT INTO wyko_file(wyko_file,file_name,date_inserted)"
                   " VALUES (%s,%s,%s)")
            cursor.execute(sql, (data, filename, curr_datetime))
            if cursor.rowcount != 0:
                self.logger.info("Transfer to database succesful!")
                cnx.commit()
        except (MySQLdb.OperationalError, MySQLdb.ProgrammingError) as e:
            self.manage_exception(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()

    def watch(self):
        """main loop that watches the directory"""  
        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.watched_folder):
                for filename in files:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    try:
                        self.logger.info("Transferring file: "+filename)
                        self.insert_csv(file_path, filename)
                    except Exception as e:
                        self.manage_exception(e)
                    else:
                        os.remove(file)
                        self.logger.info(
                            'File {} successfully removed'.format(file_path))
        except Exception as e:
            self.manage_exception(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    watcher = FolderWatcher(os.path.join('Config', 'config.ini'))
    watcher.watch()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I was also thinking of creating a class for it, but i dont know where to start. The code looks cleaner now. @Mathias

Answer (score 2):

**Use batches**

One of the issue I can see is that you are handling CSV file line-by-line.
You should consider batching your requests to ensure you are sending queries to MySQL batched for better performance.
You may be surprised with performance improvement.

See here - also search how to send queries to MySQL in batches:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526937/2075157

**A few comments**

- Don't hard-code path-separators even if you are planning to run on windows only.
  See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep

  conf_file = currdir + "\Config\config.ini"
- Use `format` function `"exception on {0}!".format(option)` instead of `%` when formatting strings for output - this is industry standard.

**Minor**

- formatting is off and not-consistent: like space after comma-separator between method arguments is not consistent - choose one standard and follow it.

**Good parts**

- logging is done great